# Mathtools and Mtpro2 curly brace

Tags: braces, mathtools, displaystyle, mtpro

In the `mathtools` package there is the `dcases` environment by which mathematical expressions are presented in `displaystyle` mode in each row of the `case` environment, as shown in the first picture.

[image]

With `mtpro2` package, the `\ccases` command offers the curly brace in the same cases environment as shown below

[image]

but every row has to be put inside `\displaystyle` command in order to produce the same result. I would like to use the `mtpro2` curly brace along with the displaystyle equations in every row without having to put every row in display mode.

Is there a way to

1. replace globally the `dcases` brace with the curly one from `mtpro2` package? Or
2. renew the `\ccases` environment so every row is in displaystyle?

Both approaches are accepted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[ \begin{dcases}
\int_{0}^{1}{x^2\ d x} & \text{1st argument}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}} & \text{2nd argument}
\end{dcases} \]

\[ \ccases{
\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{1}{x^2\ d x}} & \text{1st argument}\\
\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}} & \text{2nd argument}} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a remark; the vertical spacing between the rows of `ccases` is not very good.

Answer (score 2):

Also if ccases of `mtpro2` v. lite not has very good vertical spacing between the rows you can add at the end the `\\` your measure to increase the vertical spacing putting `[2ex]` (for example). This way you'll have more vertical space and the two codes look the same. After I have added for a very good view `newtxtext` package to have a more homogeneous stylistic coding.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[ \begin{dcases}
\int_{0}^{1}{x^2\ d x} & \text{1st argument}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}} & \text{2nd argument}
\end{dcases} \]

\[ \ccases{
\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{1}{x^2\ d x}} & \text{1st argument}\\[2ex]
\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}} & \text{2nd argument}} \]
\end{document}
```